# Participles- what are the differences in the meanings of the given sentences?

Tags: participles

Rising out of the sea in front of us, the sun started to warm our faces.

The sun started to warm our faces rising out of the sea in front of us.

The sun started to warm our faces, rising out of the sea in front of us.

Do all the above sentences mean the same?
Are they all grammatically correct?

Comment: I believe #2 would mean your faces were rising out of the sea in front of you on a very large waterproof LCD screen mounted on a Tesla submarine, which draws its power from the seawater itself. The water is cold (it must be off the coast of San Francisco) and the sun is beginning to warm the screen.  There is so much information embedded in the absent comma!

Comment: The first gets my vote for artistry, the third is understandable...